# Fullcalendar Overlapping Event Make Event Full Width

Tags: fullcalendar

How to make overlapping events 100% width? In the picture below, I want the red one to be 100% of the width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to make it 75%.  I found an element with the style:

```
inset: 312px 0% -429px 50%; 
z-index: 2;
```

In dev mode I can change that to:

```
inset: 312px 0% -429px 25%; 
z-index: 2;
```

which gets the appearance I want however I could find no way to get a callback at the correct time to make that change.  Keep in mind that that callback would have to happen every time anything on the calendar changes anything that could cause overlap to change.